# Konsole has no appearance preferences

Tags: kde, plasma

On KDE Plasma, Konsole has no appearance options... I want to have a semi-transparent background for Konsole since I use neovim and having documentation behind my terminal is very important in such a small single-display setup.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP7nz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make a new profile - all the appearance settings (including terminal transparency) are hiding there.

Click "Settings". Next, click "Manage Profiles...". Click "New...". In the window that pops up, click "Appearance" in the menu on the left side. You'll see a stack of buttons on the right side of the window, click the "Edit..." button. Set "Background transparency:" to your desired value (I have it set to 50 percent). Then click "OK" on all the windows until you're back to your terminal. Finally, click "Settings", hover over "Switch Profile", and click on the new profile.

Note that this appears to make ALL your profiles transparent (maybe because you're editing the color scheme itself, not just the profile?), so you'll need to go back and edit one of your profiles to reverse these steps if you end up not liking the results. You may also have to switch between profiles before a change takes effect.

Final result:

[image: Transparent Konsole window]